# how to calculate the correct percentage of a valuation system of products?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system of valuation of stars of products equivalent of medium and whole

**Example:**

`0.5` - `1` - `1.5` - `2` - `2.5` - `3` - `3.5` - `4` - `4.5` - `5`

I get the data correctly taking two data a medium and  whole and sum both values

From the following consultation:

```
//we define in a variable the id of the product valued by the valuation system
$id_product = 1;

//we obtain an average and integer value equivalent to 4.5 and 5
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating) as total FROM ratings WHERE id_product=? AND rating in(4.5,5)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $sum;
 }

//we obtain an average and integer value equivalent to 3.5 and 4
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating) as total FROM ratings WHERE id_product=? AND rating in(3.5,4)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $sum;
 }

//we obtain an average and integer value equivalent to 2.5 and 3
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating) as total FROM ratings WHERE id_product=? AND rating in(2.5,3)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $sum;
 }

//we obtain an average and integer value equivalent to 1.5 and 2
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating) as total FROM ratings WHERE id_product=? AND rating in(1.5,2)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $sum;
 }

//we obtain an average and integer value equivalent to 0.5 and 1
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating) as total FROM ratings WHERE id_product=? AND rating in(0.5,1)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $sum;
 }
```

now my question is how can I correctly calculate the data in percentages and get a result like the following image:

[image]

Comment: 'Sumo'? As in 'wrestle'?

Comment: @Strawberry not is so serious only has an orthographic error could be said he meant "sum"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentages in that table are based on counts, not sums of the rating values.

You can do all this in one query, you don't need separate queries for each valuation range.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
           SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
           SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
           SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
           SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
           AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
    FROM ratings
    WHERE id_product = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_product);
$stmt->execute();
$percents = array(;
$stmt->bind_result($percents[5], $percents[4], $percents[3], $percents[2], $percents[1], $avg_rating);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    for ($i in array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)) {
        echo "%i stars: " . round($percents[$i]) . "%<br>";
    }
    echo "Average rating: $avg_rating<br>";
} else {
    echo "This product is not yet rated<br>";
}
```

Comment: and in that way how to show the individual percentage as the image ie several customers vote a star 10% of customers so for example

Comment: Make the length of the bar dependent on `pct_#_star`.

Comment: PHP has image functions that let you create a rectangle of a specific size.

Comment: sorry for being so dumb, I understand what I do not understand is the following results, as I call them I get them so `$stmt->bind_result($sum);` and now must be `$stmt->bind_result($pct_1_star);` or not?

Comment: That's a lot of query.

Comment: @Strawberry 
That's a lot of query.? Of the answer or the question?

Comment: @J.Doe The answer - the Query

Comment: @Strawberry unlike the question This answer looks interesting, it's a shame I do not have an idea to answer this question.

Comment: @Alex I've added the `bind_result` call.